# Why don't people install cold air return vents into wood stove surrounds?

Tags: vent, woodstove

I've been researching how to help my woodstove better heat my house, so that warm air from the stove (on one side of the house) moves throughout the house to other rooms, heating it more evenly (vs heat being trapped in the room the stove is in). Everything I've read recommends moving cold air to the stove, rather than trying to distribute warm air from the stove.

If this is the case, why don't you ever see a cold air return vent installed in the back of a stone/brick wood stove surround? A cold air return duct could then return cold air from the farthest side of the house to the stove, and help circulate air through the house. Is a vent in a solid masonry surround considered a fire hazard? What if you used a metal vent?

Comment: Most wood stoves heat by radiation, instead pushing/forcing warm air out.  Cold air is usually use for the burning of the wood and up the chimney.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, and your combustion air should be coming from outside of the house as well. OP could install a forced air heat exchanger into the exhaust stack however.

Comment: Quite common in the form of a wood *furnace,* not out in the living room. Most wood *stove* installations (even those with a blower to extract more heat) don't turn into a hybrid furnace for various reasons, appearance being one, excess complexity and permanent building alterations for a possibly temporary appliance being another. Various "traditional" means of circulating more air don't pass firecode muster these days, for the usual reason (they killed too many people in fires in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

The stone surround is supposed to be fireproof, so you'd need to make a fireproof hole in it.  making a hole fireproof is tricky.

Comment: You could make the hole fireproof by filling it with water and sealing it into a pipe - but then you've just reinvented wet central heating.  Actually there are solutions to close up holes in the event of fire, I can see one from my desk, but they're not meant for heating

Answer (score 0):

About 40 years ago I had a wood stove in my basement and I had the same question as you. I had a local HVAC person install a large duct from the furnace's cold air duct to just above the wood stove and ran the furnace fan 24/7 to move that heat all over the house. It worked great. The main heating furnace only ran on the coldest days or when the wood stove was not working.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm following you: you installed a large duct _above_ the stove to collect hot air (via convection of hot air rising) and had it piped into the "cold air" return duct. This then was pumped through the house by the furnace fan. Is this correct?

Comment: Everything I've read says do not try to move warm air. The heat loss is too great. My house had the cold air return directly above the wood stove and I had it relocated to the foyer... one of the colder parts of the house. (also, cold air return should be on the floor in cold climates to pull in cold air and on the ceiling in hot climates to pull in hot air).  I'm specifically trying to understand why I can't pipe cold air *to* the stove.

Answer (score 0):

Because a lot of basements where woodstoves are installed are unconditioned space- they dont have HVAC heat installed.  Connecting the return on an HVAC system to a woodstove, when the woodstove is not in use, will force the system to use the cold basement air as opposed to air in conditioned space (where the return, filter, etc are located in the house.) So depending on climate - like I live in VA - people may only use the woodstove for 2 weeks in total, but use electric heat for 8 months.  We use heat way more than AC, but the climate is relatively mild.

A damper can help mitigate this issue, but still the air will take path of least resistance into the air handler.